# car crash android game

Tags: physics, android

I'd like to make a simple 2d car crashing game, where the player would drive his car into moving traffic and try to cause as much damage as possible in each level (some Burnout games had a mode like this).

The physics part of the game is the most important, I can worry about graphics later. Would engine like emini or box2d work for this kind of game? Would Android devices have enough power to handle this? For example if there were about 20 cars colliding, along with some buildings, it would be nice if I could get 20 fps.

Comment: You're thinking Showtime mode in Burnout Paradise. ;)

Comment: no, Showtime mode is overrated with the bouncing car. I'm thinking Crash mode from older Burnout games -> crash into a busy intersection and watching a crash play out.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a top down game.

I've not tried Emini, but Box2D (or Chipmunk) isn't really suited to this as they are generally geared to side on views. There is an [article](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/2dcarphys/) on [GameDev](http://www.gamedev.net) that might be of some use.

I have seen some examples of faking it with box2D but the hacks they used meant things like skidding where out the question.

I think Android devices should be able to handle it, it all depends on your implementation and graphics, sounds etc. however Android is becoming [fragmented](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/11/19/angry_birds_maker_apologizes_for_android_fragmentation_issues.html) a little and it could be a problem on some devices.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by bummzack, [b2FrictionJoint](http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2FrictionJoint.html) exists for top down, I did a quick search and couldn't find anything else about Box2D and top down.

Comment: AFAIK the newer versions of Box2D can simulate top-down physics quite well (look into b2FrictionJoint).